# Lining up input elements, off by one in Firefox

Tags: css, forms, html

I'm hoping I'm missing something simple, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why I can't line up an <input type="text"> next to an <input type="submit">.

A bit of searching on StackOverflow led me to the box-sizing property, which fixed my problem in IE, but Firefox is driving me nuts.  The two elements are now the same size, but are offset by 1 pixel.

Here's the [offending code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markwoon/nxY2K/2/).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set:

```
input[type=submit]::-moz-focus-inner{ border: 0; }
```

Changing box model seems result in this effect, but it's essentially the same problem as [this](http://christophzillgens.com/en/articles/equal-height-input-and-button-elements-in-firefox-and-safari).